# Why is libjs-jquery required by ruby2.3?

Tags: package-management, ruby

I just installed the package `ruby` in Xenial, and I noticed a couple of javascript packages where also required.  Does anyone know why they are needed by ruby?  Note that I have NOT installed ruby-on-rails.

If you see [the ruby package page for ruby 2.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ruby2.3), you can see it requires `libjs-jquery`, which basically puts a few jquery files, such as

```
/usr/share/javascript/jquery/jquery.js
```

In the file system.  Does ruby really need jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found it.  It is used by rdoc, as can be seen by [searching the ruby sources](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/search?q=jquery&unscoped_q=jquery)

e.g. the first search result is:

```
lib/rdoc/generator/template/json_index/js/searcher.js

Showing the top two matches Last indexed on 26 Jun

JavaScript

    return jQuery.grep(query.split(/(\s+|::?|\(\)?)/), function(string) {
      return string.match(/\S/);
    });
  }

  function buildRegexps(queries) {
    return jQuery.map(queries, function(query) {
```